# How to open different websites from same physical directory and different Default documents in iis7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

title says all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer [different default documents using rewrite map](http://forums.iis.net/t/1163534.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No, because as you found out, web.config files are universal and therefore step on each other if two Sites share a single directory. Two sites in the same directory is permitted, two sites *with different local settings* is not.

Comment: it is possible. See link in my answer, guy there uses Rewrite Module to modify Default Document